# SQL Identify Auto Increment from a certain number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to auto increment my primary key, by 0.1 each time. Starting from 0.1. Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
 (
ID    BigInt    IDENTITY    NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. BigInt is a 8 byte **`integer`** value. 
Note: Assuming as Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

No, even if you changed the data type of the field, the identity increment 'must be a non-zero integral number containing 18 digits or less'
(Presuming this is sql server)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the Identity column cannot contain decimal values in its seed or increment.

Why would you need to do this -- for presentation purposes?  If so, don't.  If needed, one option is to create a trigger.  You could also consider using a Computed column instead -- make it 1/10 the value of the Id (your Identity field seeded and incremented at 1 -- Identity(1,1)).

Again, not sure why you'd need to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Some solution would be a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_NewTable AS
SELECT ID/10
FROM NewTable
```